# Is there a Oracle Mobile Authenticator (based on Google Authenticator) clone for Ubuntu?

Tags: oracle

I am looking for a way to generate  Oracle Mobile Authenticator OTP on Linux. Oracle Mobile Authenticator is based on Google Authenticator. So I figured I should be able to use [JAuth](https://github.com/harvardinformatics/JAuth) (Java based Google Authenticator Token generator app). But it seems like I am not able to initialize JAuth using the Secret generated by the Oracle Access Manager for the OTP.

Answer (score 0):

Google Authenticator complies to HOTP/TOTP (RFC 4226 6328)
Take a look at oathtool, which is a command line implementation of HOTP/TOTP.

Comment: oathtool is little bit too command line-ish for our user base. So we are looking at JAuth and WinAuth. Both of them should technically work. Just not able to figure out how to initialize them with the Oracle Access Manager generate Secret Key.

Comment: Are you sure, you want to use a desktop application for your users? How does the generated secret key look like?